# Do my cast-iron plumbing stacks need replacement?

Tags: plumbing, water, basement, cast-iron

Just bought a new home, and we're planning on doing some renovation.  One area of concern is the cast-iron stacks in the basement: we want to eventually finish the basement, but if these are liable to cause problems down the road we'd rather get ahead of the issues since they'll be encased in walls.

One of the stacks - I'll call it "primary" reaches all the way to the roof; I see it in the attic.  It services the only full bathroom, and nothing else right now.

The other stacks - I'll call "secondary" - does not seem to reach into the roof, I see a small pipe in the attic but it's maybe just a little vent?  It's definitely not the same diameter as the rest of the stack, and seems to go horizontally out toward the backyard.  Couldn't get good pictures of it without crawling into asbestos-land, so I'll hold off on that unless it's really necessary.  It services the kitchen on the main floor, and a single toilet, utility sink, and clothes washer in the basement.  This stack has what might be a "barnacle" or "wart" on it?  I've heard them described but what I see doesn't seem to match images I've found online.

I've included pictures of the stacks in question, which mostly look good (to my untrained eye) but might date back as far as '52 when the house was constructed.

We're also going to want to rotate the PVC bathtub drain going into the primary stack to make it easier to enclose in a wall, is that going to be an issue?

Primary Stack top:
[image: Primary stack top]

Primary Stack Bottom:
[image: Primary stack bottom]

Secondary Stack Top:
[image: Secondary Stack Top]

Secondary Stack Potential Barnacle Detail:
[image: Secondary stack potential barnacle detail]

Secondary Stack Top (alternate angle):
[image: Secondary Stack Top (alternate angle)]

Secondary Stack Bottom:
[image]

Additionally, I know our electric is terrible - and if we touch things to make modifications, we'll have to bring some other parts up to code.  Are there similar issues with these?

Finally: if we need repairs/replacement, are we more in the <$1K range, the <$3K range, or higher?

Comment: Just a comment, since I know (unfortunately) very little about plumbing. Regarding the electric: (a) post a new question with a picture of the existing panel(s) and some details such as: are most receptacles grounded? where (if anywhere) do you have GFCI/receptacles? what major appliances are electric (oven? cooktop? water heater? dryer?), what type of HVAC? In most areas, you don't have to upgrade parts of the electrical system to new code unless you are working on those parts, which makes a big difference. But the devil is in the details...

Comment: @manassehkatz-Moving2Codidact Most everything is 2-prong (despite there being in-wall AC units that require 3-prong that they HAD to be using unsafely) and scares me.  I don't trust any of it, and I want to upgrade to 200A service and relocate the panel anyway, so I'm ripping it all out.

Comment: "Ripping it all out" will almost certainly require putting in GFCI and/or AFCI on almost every circuit. Which gets expensive. An upgrade to 200A (did it last year, 1950s house) with the panel in essentially the same place (which is what I did) does *not* usually trigger those requirements except on circuits that get replaced or changed in other ways. If you really need (or want) to relocate the panel (outside to inside or from one room to another) then it is a different story altogether. As far as grounds, you *might* find, as I have, that grounds are available in most circuits and that you

Comment: can replace 2-prong with 3-prong grounded without having to run ground wires or new cables. There are other ways to deal with grounding as well, so "rip and replace everything" may or may not actually make sense.

Comment: @manassehkatz-Moving2Codidact I know about the AFCI/GFCI requirements and I'm planning on meeting them, even if it gets expensive - I can do most of the work myself and have familiarized myself with the electric code quite a bit in the last couple weeks.  Relocating the panel is basically a must since the current location prevents us from finishing the basement, so... rather have the peace of mind that it's done right.

Comment: Short of rip and replace everything, you may want to consider using the old panel *box* as a giant junction box. You can then patch most of the existing circuits through that box with extensions of appropriate cable. That can save a lot of work replacing circuits going through walls all over the house. There will likely be some circuits that are so messed up that you don't want to do that or where the distance to the new panel is so short that it is easier to rewire, but it can save a lot of time and trouble. Particularly if the existing cables have ground wires.

Comment: What's this asbestos land?

Comment: The attic has insulations that is likely asbestos-containing.  @aquaticapetheory

Comment: @manassehkatz-Moving2Codidact That's a great call for some of the newer circuits, thanks!  Particularly the AC has a good-looking cable, and maybe the dryer too.  Some of the kitchen has GFCI so I'll take a look at those ones.

Comment: You should get that tested.  Grab a sample and take it to a local asbestos testing place.  They are easy to find on google.  Is it a particular type of insulation that you know contains asbestos or are you just talking out of general pessimism?

Comment: @aquaticapetheory A little bit of A, a little bit of B.  I don't remember the exact name of the insulation type - it's kind of gravel-looking - but the inspector (when we bought the house) said it was often asbestos-containing, especially given the construction period.

Comment: Asbestos and lead paint get a bad rap, but they are usually quite safe to have in a home till you start to fool with them.  No sanding/licking/chewing on lead paint and you don't start rolling around/disturbing asbestos, you are okay.

Comment: if you ever hang out in the basement, you'll appreciate how much quieter iron pipes are than pvc; as such, i wouldn't trade them unless they needed it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There's no easy answer to "Should I replace my cast iron waste stack?".  Their average life span is 80 to 100 years.  Yours is 70 ish years old.  Some parts of it may fail tomorrow, or the whole thing may last another hundred years.

So you take a gamble.

If you replace the basement portion of it now, and if it *would have* lasted another hundred years, you've wasted a few thousand bucks.

OTOH, if you leave it alone and it develops a leak in 15 years, it's not a big deal to open the drywall box you've build around it.  That's a small extra cost. It looks to be in pretty good shape.  So maybe leaving it is the right bet?   That's a question not a decision.

OTOOH ... if your [squishy bath tub](https://diy.stackexchange.com/q/271396/65210) is directly above either of these stacks, and you'll be replacing that tub soon, that changes the equation.  If you're opening walls and floors and have access to parts of the stack both above and below a floor .... and that stack is 70 years old ... you're unlikely to have another good opportunity to replace it without doing MAJOR damage to your home, during your lifetime.    And yet ... it seems to be in pretty good shape, and you just bought a house, so are you really looking for "best practices" that will suck another 15 grand out of your wallet?  Again, that's a question not a decision.

I hope this helps a little.